# How to write super long dictionaries cleaner in function arguments?

Tags: python, argh

I am using Argh in Python 3.6 to create a complex command-line function, but because of my deep configuration file, getting a default value for an argument in the function takes a long string of dictionary keys.

This does not look particularly readable because there is a dictionary value as a key of another dictionary. It could get even more nested than 
this.

There can be more arguments with default values like this, so keeping this up would get even more confusing soon. This is and example with just one default argument:

```
import argh
import config

@arg('-v', '--version')
def generate(
    kind,
    version=config.template[config.data['default']['template']]['default']['version']):
    return ['RETURN.', kind, version]
```

The version argument default value is retrieved from my config module that generates a lot of data in list and dictionary formats.
To try and better explain the default value:

```
config.template[ # dictionary containing variables for a particular template
    config.data['default']['template'] # the default template name set in the main configuration
]['default']['version'] # The default version variable within that particular template
```

What do you recommend to keep this more readable?

Comment: Possibly, you're looking for something like [easydict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easydict/) or [treedict](http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/treedict/overview.html) (or myriad other variations of the same idea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use the same trick used for mutable default values. This gives you more room to write something more readable.

```
@arg('-v', '--version')
def generate(kind, version=None):
    if version is None:
        d = config.data['default']['template']
        version = config.template[d]['default']['version']   
    return ['RETURN.', kind, version]
```

One drawback is that this is *techinically* different, as the data in `config.data` (or any of the dicts) could change between when the function is defined and when it is run. You can do the dict lookups once before the function is defined to mitigate that.

```
# Choose whatever refactoring looks good to you
default_template = config.data['default']['template']
default_version = config.template[default_template]['default']['version']

@arg('-v', '--version')
def generate(kind, version=default_version):
    return ['RETURN.', kind, version]

del default_template default_version  # Optional
```

Comment: I ended up finding the _addict_ Python library and will consider applying either or both of those refactorings, depending on the function.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it on one line:

```
default_template_id = config.data['default']['template']
default_template = config.template[default_template_id]
default_version = default_template['default']['version'] 

def generate(kind, version=default_version):
    return ['RETURN.', kind, version]
```